# Ajax response how to Reload JQuery(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsf-2

Our application is JSF2 framework when we make Ajax Calls in certain scenarios we need to re-invoke the java-script(jQuery-for UI style)  ,when the Ajax response returns back from server.

The javascripts are not getting called ,when the Ajax response come back..

Is there any way to enable this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either* use [`jQuery.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (depending on jQuery version) instead to reapply the functions on every change in the HTML DOM tree, e.g.:

```
jQuery(selector).on(eventName, callbackFunction);
```

*or* let JSF re-invoke the JS functions by specifying an JSF ajax event handler by `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`, e.g.:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") { // Can be 'begin', 'complete' and 'success'.
        // Re-invoke your JS functions here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Balucs...is there evenName for Ajax is Load ?jQuery(selector).on("load", callbackFunction);

Comment: For example, yes. It's just the standard HTML DOM event name. You only need to keep in mind the `load` event isn't invoked on ajax responses. You rather want to modify whatever you're doing inside the existing onload function.

Comment: Just to clarify ,so this jQuery.on will not be called if iput the "load" event.

Comment: No because it's fired only once. You need `addOnEvent()` here. Or to use `on()` on whatever you're doing **inside** your current onload handler function. E.g. `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(someSelector).click(someCallback); });` should then be `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(someSelector).on("click", someCallback); });` .

Comment: You're talking about `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()`? You need to ensure that it is fired *after* the auto-included JSF JavaScript. Put it in `$(document).ready()` or something.

Comment: This works for IE and FF ,    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") { // Can be 'begin', 'complete' and 'success'.
        // Re-invoke your JS functions here.
    }
});